# Booking logic doesn't work

Tags: java, date, iteration, compareto

I am implementing a programm that creates and vehicle manager, with vehicle(objects) and those vehicle objects contain booking objects (with two Strings, one for the beginning date, and one for the end date) So I did some booking tests and it doesnt work. It must be in this method.

```
    public boolean isBookable(Booking wishedBooking) {

    boolean bookable = false;

    if ((wishedBooking.begin.compareTo(begin) != 1
            && wishedBooking.end.compareTo(begin) != 1)
            || (wishedBooking.begin.compareTo(end) != -1
                && wishedBooking.end.compareTo(end) != -1)) {
        bookable = true;
    }

    return bookable;             
}
```

What I tried to do is to use compareTo. The dates have the format: YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM

So the only way the attempt booking can be done is when the begining and end of it is bellow or above one of the booking. If in one case it is not like that, it means that it cant be booked since at one time period of the time interval, there is already a booking. I am using != because it is possible that it can be equal, so the result will be 0.

The vehicle object now iterated with an methode over all the booking objects to check whether the booking can be done, os it is bookable.

Where is the mistake?

Comment: are you sure that the compareTo() method works on your date-format? what object do you store your dates in, String or Date ?

Comment: I'm not sure what the exact cause of the problem is, but it might be fixed by parsing the dates using [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and then using [`Date.before`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#before(java.util.Date)) and [`Date.after`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#after(java.util.Date)). That would probably make your code a lot more readable, too.

Comment: @SaraSeppola I tried in in another class in order to check whether its working or not. The date is stored in two Strings, the beginning and the end. They are both stored in the booking object.

Comment: @andersschuller Well, I would like to follow your advice, but since thats a homework, I have to follow the instructions.

Comment: okay, since the dates are in String-format, the compareTo() will probably just compare the dates lexicographically

Comment: @SaraSeppola ummm, and that means it isnt working for numbers?

Comment: well, lexicographically i think that 143 > 1222 because the values are checked from left to right... but since all the dates you have are in the same format, starting with year, then month etc, i think that also the String can work in this case. If not, use instead javas Date() object. and check @Mureinik 's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contract of `a.compareTo(b)` is to return a value greater than 0 if `a` is "larger" than `b`, a value smaller than 0 if it's "smaller" or 0 if they are equal. Using 1 and -1 is purely an implementation detail, and you should not rely on it. I.e., your should change your code to:

```
public boolean isBookable(Booking wishedBooking) {

    boolean bookable = false;

    if ((wishedBooking.begin.compareTo(begin) <= 0
            && wishedBooking.end.compareTo(begin) <= 0)
            || (wishedBooking.begin.compareTo(end) >= 0
                && wishedBooking.end.compareTo(end) >= 0)) {
        bookable = true;
    }

    return bookable;             
}
```

Note that since you're only returning a `boolean`, the `if` can be removed, and you can just return its condition:

```
public boolean isBookable(Booking wishedBooking) {
    return ((wishedBooking.begin.compareTo(begin) <= 0
            && wishedBooking.end.compareTo(begin) <= 0)
            || (wishedBooking.begin.compareTo(end) >= 0
                && wishedBooking.end.compareTo(end) >= 0));
}
```

Comment: Wait, does that mean that it can also be another number that is not 1 ? If it says it is just bigger than 0 that means it could be something else, right?

Comment: Oh my god, thank you so much. Now everything is fine. What a stupid mistake. Thanks alot!

Comment: @DennisvonEich Yes, it can definitely be any number larger than `0`. E.g., with the java version I have installed locally (1.7.0_45), `"2014/04/27 23:00".compareTo("2011/11/16 23:00")` yields `3`.

Comment: Well I got a little problem, maybe its not a big problem so I ask it here. My test class works only in 50% of the cases. I cant see any reason why it is working just in 50% of the cases.

Comment: It's pretty hard to answer without the test class' source code. Could you please open a new post with the test class' source and a description of how it fails?